# Linear Regression plot

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression

I'm new to pandas I wanted to know why does the graph look like this when I plot it?

[image: here]
Code:

```
plt.scatter(X_train.iloc[:,10], y_train, color='red',label='Actual data')
plt.plot(X_train.iloc[:,10], y_train_pred, color='green',label='Predicted data')
```

I want it to look something like this, anyone willing to point out where the problem falls?
[image: this]

Comment: you would need to get the slope and intercept of your linear model as a first step, and use that information to plot a line over the range of your plot

Comment: I cannot tell you why your predictions are not on one line. But the jumping back and forth comes from the ordering of the values. Sort your values to solve that.